# (clang AST matchers) How to match consecutive statements?

Tags: c++, clang++, clang-tidy, clang-ast-matchers

I'm planning a bunch of refactorings on a large code base that I'd like to automate using Clang tooling. For this, I'm trying to write a Clang AST Matcher expression.

Specifically, I'm trying to match pairs of statements that I'd like to replace with something else, like

```
 a();      =>     a_and_b(x);
 b(x);
```

So I'm trying to match an `a` callExpr() followed by a `b` callExpr() (but could be any statement, really). I have constructed matchers for the first and the second statements, independently, let's call them `aMatcher()` and `bMatcher()` but haven't found how to combine them so that they match only if they're back-to-back, something like `bMatcher(follows(aMatcher())`. None of the existing matchers seems to be pertinent (looked for "next", "prev", "position", ...).

How do I go about this the correct way, please?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `UseAnyOfAllOfCheck` contains a private `nextStmt` matcher:

```
/// Matches a Stmt whose parent is a CompoundStmt, and which is directly
/// followed by a Stmt matching the inner matcher.
AST_MATCHER_P(Stmt, nextStmt, ast_matchers::internal::Matcher<Stmt>,
              InnerMatcher) {
  DynTypedNodeList Parents = Finder->getASTContext().getParents(Node);
  if (Parents.size() != 1)
    return false;

  auto *C = Parents[0].get<CompoundStmt>();
  if (!C)
    return false;

  const auto *I = llvm::find(C->body(), &Node);
  assert(I != C->body_end() && "C is parent of Node");
  if (++I == C->body_end())
    return false; // Node is last statement.

  return InnerMatcher.matches(**I, Finder, Builder);
}
```

I don't know how robust that is, but I'll try to use it and report back.